# MFC CString Linker error between two projects

Tags: c++, mfc, cstring, unicode-string

I have 2 projects in c++ (MFC)
One is a library project which im using in the second one (an executable one).

They work together great, until I call a function from the regular project that takes a CString as argument. I get a linker error like this

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall 
CTextDisplay::SetText1(class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,
class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >)" (?SetText1@CTextDisplay@@QAEXV?$CStringT@_WV?
$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z) referenced in function 
"public: void __thiscall CManualPane::SetBeadCountFor(int,double)" 
(?SetBeadCountFor@CManualPane@@QAEXHN@Z)    C:\source\IQ-Project\IQ\ManualPane.obj  IQ
```

The executable project has its character set to  UNICODE but the Library has it set to Multy-Byte chatacter set. I really can't change them without getting ridiculous amounts of errors.

Any suggestions?

Edit: The reason we have different settings in these two projects is because the Executable project is basically an external project that my group didn't build or create. We just had to bring it in and use it. The library project is something we've all been working on for a couple years.

Comment: Calling a function in the library that takes an int (for example) presents no problems

Comment: I'm not sure which one you refer to as *regular project* but assuming you're calling a function in the library project that returns a `CString`, try storing the return value as a `CStringA` in the exe project. But even if that compiles successfully, I'd be wary of passing MFC types from the library if the UNICODE settings of the two differ.

Comment: Argument of type `CString` is quite evil thing to do while designing the interface of the library.

Comment: @LihO: what kind of possible problems are there?

Comment: maybe you will have to convert from A to W (or W to A) while calling this function

Comment: If library needs to use MFC classes internally, so be it. But why bother those who will use my library with it. I'd definitely let the caller pass `std::string` or `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: by regular project i meant it produces an executable. As opposed to the library project. I am passing the CString to a function in the Library

Comment: @irco Then convert it to a `CStringA` within the exe before calling the library function. I believe this can be done by `CStringA cstra( source_cstr.GetString() ); libfunction( cstra );`

Comment: @Praetorian There is no implicit conversion between CStringA and CString, it just gives me a mismatching parameter types error

Comment: @LihO Your argument is about as constructive as *MFC is evil, don't use it.* The merits / demerits of MFC non-withstanding, there's nothing wrong in passing around MFC types as long as the entire application is MFC based, and that's the extent of its scope. MFC was designed to be able to pass its types around as long as everything was build with MFC support. The OP is running into trouble because he has differing settings across various modules, something that is definitely not recommended.

Comment: @LihO The executable project is just an external project my group had to take and update(and the project is gigantic). We didn't write it. WE did write the library  and we have been building on it for a couple years now. It wasn't our choice to have different settings as far as the character set

Comment: @irco [The constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cws1zdt8.aspx) taking the `YCHAR*` argument is supposed to convert from A to W and vice-versa. The conversion is not implicit, you'll have to create an intermediate variable.

Comment: I did use an intermediate variable just like you recommended in your two lines of code, but when passing it to the library's method the compile error (different types) comes up

Comment: @Praetorian: I haven't said a single word against MFC. I just said that there are more reasonable ways how to pass a string to the library function than passing it as a `CString`.

Comment: @LihO I never said you were criticizing MFC either; I only likened your earlier comment to being as constructive as criticism of MFC in a post where someone's seeking help about MFC. What I'm trying to say is when you're playing within the confines of a certain framework, there's nothing *unreasonable* about passing around its types, if the framework has been designed to support that. That being said, in this particular case, your suggestion might be the easiest solution for the OP - to package the contents of the CString in a type that doesn't care about the UNICODE setting of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it proved to be a better idea to avoid having unicode and multybyte projects in the same solution so I moved it all to unicode and went from there

Answer (score 3):

When you include the headers of the library project in the executable, there is likely a typedef which is used in the declaration of the function. Since the executable uses UNICODE, the declaration is now in UNICODE. However, the library implementation is still in MultiByte and so the definition doesn't match the declaration leading to the linker error.

Look into how these typedefs are being setup, and you might be able to do some special #define, #undef around the included header.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I'm not sure where do I need to start looking. stdafx has no reference to CString nor do i know exactly where else any of these typedefs could be

Comment: the table at the bottom might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea(v=vs.80).aspx